# Duplicate information from sql result

Tags: php, mysql

I looked in about 18 other posts on here an most people are asking how to delete the records not just hide them. So my problem: I have a database with staff members who are associated with locations. Many of the staff members are associated with more than one location. What I want to do is to only display the first location listed in the mysql result and skip over the others. I have the sql query linking the tables together and it works aside from it showing the same information for those staff members that are in those other locations multiple times so example would be like this:

[image]

This is the sql statement I have currently

```
    SELECT staff_tbl.staffID, staff_tbl.firstName, staff_tbl.middleInitial, staff_tbl.lastName,
     location_tbl.locationID, location_tbl.staffID, 
    officelocations_tbl.locationID, officelocations_tbl.officeName, staff_title_tbl.title_ID,
     staff_title_tbl.staff_ID, titles_tbl.titleID, titles_tbl.titleName

    FROM staff_tbl 

    INNER JOIN location_tbl ON location_tbl.staffID = staff_tbl.staffID 
    INNER JOIN officelocations_tbl ON location_tbl.locationID = officelocations_tbl.locationID
    INNER JOIN staff_title_tbl ON staff_title_tbl.staff_ID = staff_tbl.staffID 
    INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON staff_title_tbl.title_ID = titles_tbl.titleID
```

and my php is

```
      <?php do { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row_rs_Staff_Info['firstName']; ?>&nbsp; <?php echo $row_rs_Staff_Info['lastName']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_rs_Staff_Info['titleName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
  <td><?php echo $row_rs_Staff_Info['officeName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>

</tr>
<?php } while ($row_mysqlResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_mysqlResult)); ?>
```

What I would like to know is there a way using php to select only the first entry listed for each person and display that and just skip over the other two. I was thinking it could be done by possibly adding the staffID's to an array and if they are in there to skip over the next one listed in the staff_title_tbl but wasn't quite sure how to write it that way. Any help would be great thank you in advance.

Comment: Rather than choosing the 'first' matching row of each group, would it be more appropriate to choose the staff member's current location?  Does location_tbl have any sort of information that could be used to this end?  (And similarly with staff_title_tbl?)

Comment: You want a DISTICT clause on a concat of first name, inital, last name. Sorry I'm reading this on my phone so its hard to code a real answer, Ill add an example when i get home if no one has answered correctly by then

Comment: Actually DISTINCT on staffID should be sufficient in place of concatenating for a distinct name

Comment: Also when a foreign key column has the same name as the primary key, like staffID, you can use USING(staffID) instead ON location_tbl.staffID = staff_tbl.staffID.

Comment: @pilotcam about 1/3 of the staff members have multiple locations so I can't select that. The staff member doesn't necessarily live in the city that he/she is associated with.

Comment: @WebChemist I can try this along with the distinct key word and let you know if it outputs any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query on the `location_tbl` to select only one location per employee

```
SELECT staff_tbl.staffID, 
  staff_tbl.firstName, 
  staff_tbl.middleInitial, 
  staff_tbl.lastName,
  location_tbl.locationID, 
  location_tbl.staffID, 
  officelocations_tbl.locationID, 
  officelocations_tbl.officeName, 
  staff_title_tbl.title_ID,
  staff_title_tbl.staff_ID, 
  titles_tbl.titleID, 
  titles_tbl.titleName
FROM staff_tbl 
INNER JOIN
(
  select max(locationID) locationID, staffID
  from location_tbl 
  group by staffID
) location_tbl 
  ON location_tbl.staffID = staff_tbl.staffID 
INNER JOIN officelocations_tbl 
  ON location_tbl.locationID = officelocations_tbl.locationID
INNER JOIN staff_title_tbl 
  ON staff_title_tbl.staff_ID = staff_tbl.staffID 
INNER JOIN titles_tbl 
  ON staff_title_tbl.title_ID = titles_tbl.titleID
```

Comment: I have tried several times to use a second sub query in the sql statements but for some reason it always seems to throw one error or another. I can try this and will let you know what error it gives me.

Comment: @puddleJumper if you can please create a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model.  Then I can test the query.

Comment: Ok so some clarification on this. This does work with one minor hitch, it isn't pulling the first listing of the staff member. It seems to be pulling the second to last one on the list. Any ideas on correcting this?

Comment: @puddleJumper then change the MAX() to a MIN().

Comment: I have a primaryKey in that table can I set it to pull the smallest from that one instead of the other one? so instead of using select max(locationID) locationID, staffID can I do something like select max(primaryKey) locationID, staffID? I tried this but it is throwing an error or not pulling all the staff memebers

Comment: @puddlejumper you should use MIN(locationid). My suggestion would be to create a SQL fiddle with a working data model that would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok so I think this should work it took me a bit it didn't like that I had way too many characters. here is the link to the sql fiddle with the information in it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572d1/1/0

Comment: @puddleJumper thanks for the sql fiddle, now based on the data you provided what do you expect the result to be?  It looks like it is returning one record per person.

Comment: yes with your edits it is pulling just the one record per person, which is what I want it to do. But it is pulling the highest number associated with the location they are associated with. I want it to pull the first location so that I can have it be the primary location and the others are secondary ones.

Comment: @puddleJumper changing it to `MIN()` does it not give you the result you want -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572d1/2

Comment: @puddleJumper or please check this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572d1/18 -- I replaced the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` and it returns all rows for staff and replaces null value with none assigned.

Comment: sort of. I resaved the sqlfiddle so that the the first one that shows up is not the smallest number for staff member 1. So instead of Seattle it should say San Francisco. I want it to show the first location rather than the one with the smallest locationID number.

Comment: @puddleJumper how do you decide first location?

Comment: I would like it to be the first one that the sql statement comes to in the locations_tbl. Each staff member should have 1 primary location and some will have multiple other locations that they are associated with. So even if they are a member of location 2 but location 17 is their primary I want that to show instead of location 2.

Comment: @puddleJumper my suggestion would be to add a bit flag to the table to identify the primary location. This would be significantly easier.

Comment: Yea I created a second table that holds only their primary locations but was hoping not to have to use it but will if I couldn't get this to work. and keep the other one for all their locations

Comment: @puddleJumper what you are asking for is not really possible.  Unless you specify an order, sql will not know to select the first one it comes across unless it meets a specific criteria - alpha order, min/max id, etc. It has no way of knowing which one to select unless you tell it.  I would suggest instead of a second table, just using a `bit` flag on the `location_tbl` table that will identify the primary location. No need for a second table.

Comment: @puddleJumper then you would just use the following -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b226/1  -- just apply a filter where the primary location = 1 and you will return the results that you want. -- or this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b226/2

Comment: ahh I see yes that should work. When I get to home I will double check the output on the site and make sure it is displaying the proper locations for people. I knew there had to be a way without creating another table. I have it sitting on that table for the moment but wanted to switch so that I don't have unnecessary tables in the database. Thank you.

Comment: This did work sorry for the long delay in replying. Still trying to work out another issue that has come up when I want to remove a couple of columns in my original staff table. The solution for the bit worked perfectly thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mysql's DISTINCT, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(staff_tbl.staffID), staff_tbl.firstName, staff_tbl.middleInitial (.. etc)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier to this. I do have question if I put the Distinct key word wouldn't that still allow all of them to show being as each row will still be distinct? meaning that with the location changed it will be different from the first one that shows up.

Comment: DISTINCT takes an argument, in this case staffID. It does not look at the entire row. So if you get duplicate staffIDs from your query, only one of them will be in the final result

Comment: Even with that argument supplied it still displays a duplicate record for those staff members that have multiple locations. I think this is because technically they are distinct records. Yes the staff id and name and such are the same but the location isn't so it sees that as an entirely distinct record in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the use of DISTINCT(staffID) to limit repetitive staff listings, you're query could use some additional cleanup:

1) Use table aliases so you don't have to reference the entire table name for each column

2) You have redundant data in your SELECT column listing:

location_tbl.**locationID** == officelocations_tbl.**locationID**

staff_tbl.**staffID** == location_tbl.**staffID** == staff_title_tbl.**staff_ID**

staff_title_tbl.**title_ID** == titles_tbl.**titleID**

Just because you use column in a join doesn't mean you have to reference that column in your SELECT statement. And if these columns did have different values, than you would have a hard time pairing the 2 columns in a join statement.

3) Inconsistencies: you really should rename the staff_title_tbl.**staff_ID** to just staffID, and staff_title_tbl.**title_ID** to titleID so they match the column names of the other table. Notice in the cleaned up query below how we can use USING() on the staffID and locationID where the column names match, but have to write the lengthier ON when they do not. Make your names consistent so in your program you don't have to look back at the tables to see which way you named something.

4) while you may wish to write out INNER JOIN for clarity, you can just use JOIN if you prefer as this is the default JOIN type if no other specific type of join is listed.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(s.staffID)
        ,s.firstName
        ,s.middleInitial
        ,s.lastName
        ,l.locationID
        ,ol.officeName
        ,st.title_ID
        ,t.titleName
FROM    staff_tbl           AS s
JOIN    location_tbl        AS l
USING   (staffID)
JOIN    officelocations_tbl AS ol
USING   (locationID)
JOIN    staff_title_tbl     AS st
ON      st.staff_ID = s.staffID 
JOIN    titles_tbl          AS t
ON      st.title_ID = t.titleID
```

Also for your info, a way to do this within PHP using the original query you had with multiple rows, but I'm surprised the original PHP works at all considering you have your query row set called $row_rs_Staff_Info in one place and $row_mysqlResult in another...

```
<?php 
$unique = array();
do {
    $key = $row_mysqlResult['firstName'].$row_mysqlResult['lastName'];

    //if ok being last location, newer values will overwrite old for same key
    $unique[$key] = $row_rs_Staff_Info;

    //OR

    //if must be first location, check for key & dont overwrite if already set
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $unique)){
        $unique[$key] = $row_mysqlResult;
    }
} while ($row_mysqlResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_mysqlResult));

foreach($unique as $k => $v){?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $v['firstName']; ?>&nbsp; <?php echo $v['lastName']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $v['titleName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
  <td><?php echo $v['officeName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

php array keys must be unique, so you can add your combination of values that should make a unique concatenation, and if that same key value appears again in the result it would overwrite the existing value for that key with the new value. But unless you also need the larger dataset for something else on the page and you don't want to query twice, optimize in SQL not PHP so you arent wasting server resources for data you don't plan to use.

**Edit**

I loaded the sql from the fiddle link you provided, and group by does indeed eliminate duplicate Alexander Walsh rows..

```
SELECT      s.staffID
            ,s.firstName
            ,s.middleInitial
            ,s.lastName
            ,l.locationID
            ,ol.officeName
            ,st.title_ID
            ,t.titleName
FROM        staff_tbl           AS s
JOIN        location_tbl        AS l
USING       (staffID)
JOIN        officelocations_tbl AS ol
USING       (locationID)
JOIN        staff_title_tbl     AS st
ON          st.staff_ID = s.staffID 
JOIN        titles_tbl          AS t
ON          st.title_ID = t.titleID
GROUP BY    (staffID)
```

result (some columns redacted for table width):

```
staffID firstName   lastName    officeName      titleName
1       Alexander   Walsh       Seattle         Consultant
2       Bernadette  Ace         Sacramento      Consultant
3       Bert        McElway     San Antonio     Associate Consultant
5       Peter       Wallace     San Francisco   Senior Consultant
```

Comment: also with the PHP solution I posted, if 2 employees happened to have the same first & last names they would be treated as the same person, whereas with the SQL solution they would still be separate as they each have unique staffIDs.

Comment: For the php not working I didn't actually give you the entire statement. I gave you what you basically needed to know. For the sql statement I do need that information because I'm using it on the page an on a secondary page that the php links to. I did originally have the AS settings in there but when I switched to the new layout for the database it didn't like them. And I did try the DISTINCT and it sill displays multiples of each because the entire record is distinct.

Comment: well I'm just sayin that in a do{}while() sql row loop, the inner looping row variable name should be the same as the row name in the while condition. Posting inacurrate or incomplete code kinda makes it hard to help out. As for your SQL, that is strange as DISTINCT should only look at the column(s) in the DISTINCT() clause, not the entire row, but its hard to test this without seeing your tables.... The other option is instead of the DISTINCT() clause, try adding GROUP BY (staffid) to the very end of the query after the last ON statement

Comment: also just to be clear, staffID is the primary key on staff_tbl correct?

Comment: yes staffID is the primary key for the staff_tbl. I also have a primaryKey for the locations_tbl that I was hoping to use instead of the locationID

Comment: no that one didn't work either. I'm not in front of that computer at the moment, so can tell you exactly what error it was giving me. I am mainly concerned with the sql statement not the php. The php I have works they way I want. I have a sql fiddle that you can see a basic set up of the database. sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572d1/18

Comment: thanks for the fiddle link - not sure what to say, GROUP BY works for me - see post edit

Comment: Well there is a minor error in the code you provided as well. It is only pulling 4 people when there should be 5. Now my full table has currently 101 people so missing one would be harder to tell but my client will notice it. This might be because some thing is missing but even if they don't have a location they should show up.

Comment: its not missing, your original query doesnt show him either ran against the sqlfiddle you provided. Brad Bernard, staffID 4 is assigned to locationID 11, which does not exist in officelocations_tbl. If you wanted to include him with a null location, you would change (INNER) JOIN officelocations_tbl to LEFT OUTER JOIN  officelocations_tbl

Comment: have you considered using innodb tables and adding foreign key constraints to enforce referential integrity?